# I am trying to add PATH to makefile in Linux

Tags: c, makefile

I have a path:

```sh
export PATH=~icar/public/course/p6330/mpich4i/bin:$PATH
```

When I apply this to the command line, it successfully exports the file in this directory or sets my current directory path to its contents. I am trying to do this same thing in my makefile and am not having much success. Here is what I have based on the answers I've found on the web but I believe I am missing something.

```
PATH = $PATH:~icar/public/course/p6330/mpich4i/bin:$PATH

all: p4

export PATH

p4: p4.c
    mpicc -g -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror p4.c -o p4

clean:
    rm -rf *.o p4
```

Comment: Did you deliberately add the blank in `$PATH: ~icar/public/...` ? Furthermore, you probably need to enclose PATH in parenthesis (like `$(CC)` and `$(LIBS)`). An alternative could be to use full qualified paths.

Comment: I took away the unnecessary lines that were commented out and took away the blank. I still get make error

Comment: By "use full qualified paths do you mean like this:  export PATH=~icar/public/course/p6330/mpich4i/bin:$PATH

Comment: Is `~icar` meant to be `~/icar`? Your snippet would add `$PATH` twice. You probably should remove one of them.

Comment: I'm unsure how to write it in makefile directly. But this line works in my command line:  export PATH=~icar/public/course/p6330/mpich4i/bin:$PATH     I can not directly add this line to my makefile because it doesn't work. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Make is not the shell and a makefile is not a shell script.  Just because something works at the shell prompt doesn't mean it will work in a makefile.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html

Comment: By using full qualified paths I mean writing `/home/icar/public/course/p6330/mpich41/bin/mpicc` instead of plain `mpicc`

Comment: @Ronald Thank you for clarifying. I'm still working on my understanding of PATHS and makefile.

Answer (score 0):

First, values like `$PATH` are shell variable references, and you are working in a makefile, so that won't work.

Second, as the commenters mention, tokens like `~` for home directories are shell features as well.

Third, in make it's illegal to use simple assignment like `=` to assign a variable to a value containing a reference to itself: that leads to an infinite recursion (actually make detects this and will fail).

To do what you want, do this:

```
PATH := $(PATH):/home/icar/public/course/p6330/mpich4i/bin
```

(assuming that the home directory of the user `icar` is `/home/icar`)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand that (~, =, and $PATH) were not allowed in the makefile. But it now works with your suggestions.